# How can I recover from deleting regedit?

Tags: windows-registry, regedit

I erased my `regedit` by mistake. I deleted it by typing it into the search bar in Windows 7, right-clicking and selecting "delete." Now when I type `regedit` in the search bar, it shows no results. How can I get it back?

Comment: Did you also remove it from the recycle bin?

Comment: Have you checked in your recycle bin?

Comment: I also deletedd if from my recycle-bin.:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [web service](http://www.regedit.us/tag/download-regedit-for-vista/) for those who suffer from missing or corrupt `regedit.exe`.

You can [download the Windows 7 version](http://www.regedit.us/regedit_download/win7/regedit.exe) of `regedit.exe` directly.

Once downloaded, just copy regedit to your `C:\Windows` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test this but `sfc /scannow` is supposed to check system files for integrity. That should include regedit.exe too and restore it if broken/missing - just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find it over c:\Windows if you dont find it you can get it from another windows instalation (a frind computer) and copy to the same directory, just get attention to you system version, if it is 32 or 64.

Comment: In Windows 7 it's directly in `C:\Windows`